# How to copy text using MuPDF?

Tags: android, mupdf

I'm using MuPDF lib in android platform. And i want to extract text from pdf file. I've got an example from [Github](https://github.com/pennygithub/Android-MuPDF-master), that shows pdf files normally.

So, is it possible to extract text from pdf using MuPDF and copy the texts ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can extract the text from PDF.

If you got the library sample you can see the following code in MuPDFPageView.java

```
@Override
protected TextWord[][] getText() {
    return mCore.textLines(mPageNumber);
}
```

This will extract the text from PDF by page number.

See the usage of below method you will get idea about how selection and copy text works

```
@TargetApi(11)
public boolean copySelection() {
    final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    processSelectedText(new TextProcessor() {
        StringBuilder line;

        public void onStartLine() {
            line = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public void onWord(TextWord word) {
            if (line.length() > 0)
                line.append(' ');
            line.append(word.w);
        }

        public void onEndLine() {
            if (text.length() > 0)
                text.append('\n');
            text.append(line);
        }
    });

    if (text.length() == 0)
        return false;

    int currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.content.ClipboardManager cm = (android.content.ClipboardManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

        cm.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("MuPDF", text));
    } else {
        android.text.ClipboardManager cm = (android.text.ClipboardManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        cm.setText(text);
    }

    deselectText();

    return true;
}
```